# Pylance: use Mypy for autocomplete

Tags: python, mypy, pylance

I have python code that uses `__getattr__` to relay non existing member accesses to another object.

I have written a Mypy plugin which makes the type hints work.

```py
class StrProxy(Proxy[str])
    s: str

    def __init__(self, s: str):
        self.s = s

    def get(self) -> str:
        return self.s

    def __deref__(self) -> str:
        return s

sp = StrProxy("test")
sp.get # exists according to mypy & pylance
sp.encode # exists according to mypy only (because of my plugin)
```

The problem: Pylance uses its own type checker (Pyright) for autocomplete.

Is there any way I can tell Pylance to use Mypy? Or switch pylance for an LSP that respects Mypy?

Comment: Language server (autocomplete) != typechecker. Langserver offers results of type checking to you, but not other way around: autocomplete stays separate. Please clarify your intent: do you want to see results of `mypy` typechecking instead of `pyright` warnings or to make some attributes shown in the autocomplete prompt? There should be such plugin for all major IDEs for the former, and the latter is impossible (`mypy` does simply not offer such functionality, neither pyright does).

Comment: @STerliakov like I said, I want pylance to use Mypy instead of Pyright. Which means I want to see the results of mypy's checks in the autocomplete - the first option you mentioned. I couldn't find any way to do that myself.

Comment: Again, neither mypy nor pyright provide autocomplete suggestions - it's a job of another component. Do you want to see errors display (warnings by mypy or pyright) or autocomplete? The former is just a matter of installing mypy plugin, probably (you may start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023678/trying-to-add-mypy-into-pycharm)), and the latter is just impossible by design.

Comment: @STerliakov let me ask - because that might be the root of my misunderstanding - when pylance wants to autocomplete an attribute name, does it not get the attribute list via Pyright? If it doesn't, then how?

Comment: Unfortunately, Pylance is closed-source (so I don't use it and can hardly reason about the internals). To learn the how you'd need access to its source. Pyright is more than type checker, it provides more options (https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/tree/main/packages/pyright-internal/src/languageService), including langserver. Mypy is definitely only a type checker and does not emit anything related to IDE autocomplete. Consult the LSP ["standard"](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/) for some more details (mypy does not follow it)